# Unexpected Overlapping instances error

Tags: haskell, types, monads, overlapping-instances

I have the following code. `Class1` instances say what the direct superclass is of a class, `SuperClass1` automatically traverses `Class1` to find all superclasses. (I have omitted the actual methods of these classes because they are not relevant for my issue.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds, RankNTypes, ConstraintKinds, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Class1 b h | h -> b
instance Class1 Functor Applicative
instance Class1 Applicative Monad

class SuperClass1 b h
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} SuperClass1 b b
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (SuperClass1 b c, Class1 c h) => SuperClass1 b h
```

This works great! Now I want to use it like this:

```
newtype HFree c f a = HFree { runHFree :: forall g. c g => (forall b. f b -> g b) -> g a }

instance SuperClass1 Functor c => Functor (HFree c f)
instance SuperClass1 Applicative c => Applicative (HFree c f)
instance SuperClass1 Monad c => Monad (HFree c f)

test :: (a -> b) -> HFree Monad f a -> HFree Monad f b
test = fmap
```

(I.e. I can give an instance of `Functor` for `Hfree c f` whenever `Functor` is a superclass of `c`.)

And this gives this error in the Applicative instance (and similar for the Monad instance):

```
• Overlapping instances for SuperClass1 Functor c1
    arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
  Matching instances:
    instance [overlappable] forall k k k (b :: k) (c :: k) (h :: k).
                            (SuperClass1 b c, Class1 c h) =>
                            SuperClass1 b h
      -- Defined at superclass.hs:17:31
    instance [overlapping] forall k (b :: k). SuperClass1 b b
      -- Defined at superclass.hs:16:30
  (The choice depends on the instantiation of ‘c1, k1’
   To pick the first instance above, use IncoherentInstances
   when compiling the other instance declarations)
• In the instance declaration for ‘Applicative (HFree c f)’
```

As far as I understand, what happens is that an Applicative instance requires a Functor instance, so the Applicative instance also needs the `SuperClass1 Functor c` constraint from Functor. And indeed if I add this, the error goes away. (This is what I currently have: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-functors-0.7/docs/Data-Functor-HFree.html)

But somehow GHC is smart enough to understand that `SuperClass1 Applicative c` implies `SuperClass1 Functor c`, because it doesn't complain about a missing constraint. Instead it gets stuck on an overlapping instances error. It would be great if there's a way to fix the error, but I can't figure out how!

Comment: The error is not related to `test` - the `Monad` and `Applicative` instances fail with an overlap error, because your instances are overlapping very badly. The only constraint of the form `SuperClass1 a b` that the compiler will be able to solve here is `SuperClass1 a a` - that is, when the types are a-priori known to be the same. In all other cases, it will give you an error. (also note, GHC doesn't even know that `SuperClass1 Functor c` implies `Functor` when `c` holds - as far as it is concerned, `SuperClass1` actually contains no information)

Comment: not sure if it's related to what you're asking but reading it as Prolog, `(SuperClass1 b c, Class1 c h) => SuperClass1 b h` should be `(Class1 c h, SuperClass1 b c) => SuperClass1 b h`. See if this changes anything. Shooting in the dark here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But somehow GHC is smart enough to understand that `SuperClass1 Applicative c` implies `SuperClass1 Functor c`, because it doesn't complain about a missing constraint.

I fear you are being too hopeful - GHC is probably working its way from the other end and giving up immediately: it sees `fmap` and tries to check that `HFree` is a `Functor`. It has only one instance to pick from: `SuperClass1 Functor c => Functor (HFree c f)`. Then, it starts trying to satisfy the constraint on that instance (`SuperClass1 Functor c`) and suddenly realizes it doesn't know what to do - there are two instances it could pick:

- `SuperClass1 b b`
- `SuperClass1 b h`

Notice that I left out the constraints on these instances - that's because *GHC needs to commit to an instance before even looking at the constraints on the left hand side*. With that said, @user2407038's comment is quite true: your instances overlap pretty badly - GHC doesn't know a priori  if it should try to unify `b ~ Functor` and `b ~ c` or `b ~ Functor` and `h ~ c`. Both could work.

If it was the case that picking *either* would work, you should turn on `IncoherentInstances`. This is, unfortunately, not the case here. You *know* that you want the second instance picked, but GHC doesn't.

---

I've recently been [toying around with a similar sort of problem but in relation to subtyping](https://gist.github.com/harpocrates/38ec83098cd45d7e8bccbb2d7001acb5) but no matter how you go about it, instance resolution is really hard. My advice to you is to use type families when you can.

## EDIT

Here is a solution to get your code to compile, except relying on type families instead of type-classes. The setup machinery is

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds, ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Kind (Constraint)

-- Find transitively all the superclasses of a constraint (including itself)
type family SuperClasses (x :: k -> Constraint) :: [k -> Constraint]
type instance SuperClasses Functor = '[Functor]
type instance SuperClasses Applicative = Applicative ': SuperClasses Functor
type instance SuperClasses Monad = Monad ': SuperClasses Applicative

-- Type level version of `elem` which is a Constraint
type family Elem (x :: k) (xs :: [k]) :: Constraint where
  Elem a (a ': bs) = ()
  Elem a (b ': bs) = Elem a bs

-- Type level version of checking the first list is a subset of the second
type family Subset (xs :: [k]) (ys :: [k]) :: Constraint where
  Subset '[] bs = ()
  Subset (a ': as) bs = (Elem a bs, Subset as bs)

-- Tell us whether the constraint x is a sub-constraint (thereby implied by) y
type x <: y = SuperClasses x `Subset` SuperClasses y
```

Then, applied to `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad`, we need

```
-- I've cropped the body of HFree since it is of no interest here
data HFree c f a

instance Functor     <: c => Functor     (HFree c f)
instance Applicative <: c => Applicative (HFree c f)
instance Monad       <: c  => Monad      (HFree c f)
```

And here are some tests

```
-- Compiles
test1 :: (a -> b) -> HFree Monad f a -> HFree Monad f b
test1 = fmap

-- Compiles
test2 :: a -> HFree Monad f a
test2 = pure

-- Doesn't compile
test3 :: a -> HFree Functor f a
test3 = pure
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks! I'll give the bounty when I get the chance to check the solution this weekend.

Comment: Got it working, see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-functors-0.7.1/docs/src/Data-Constraint-Class1.html 
Using type families like this is a really neat trick!